# Why can't I save to the external storage using my code?

Tags: android, save, android-external-storage

I'm trying to write a program that will need tot save to external storage. Right now I cant seem to save to the external storage.

I included the necessary permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

My code is a simple test for writing to external storage.

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/" + "test.jpg";                
            File file = new File(path);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I have run this code on an emulator and a physical device. In neither case do I see a file saved to the Pictures Folder. Really need help with this.

Comment: can you paste the code for createNewFile() method ?

Comment: It's a method in the File Class. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#createNewFile()

Comment: What is the android version in physical device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android M+ you need to request permission not only in Manifest but at runtime also

```
private void requestPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        ActivityCompat
                .requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    } else {
        //your permission was already granted then write to storage        
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
               // here you write to the storage for the first time
            } else {
                // Permission Denied               
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. I didn't see any of this in the documentation.

Comment: Glad it helped ) It is on the page runtime permissions on Android developers. Go though it if you want to know more